# Can I continue playing Dying Light online after my Xbox Live Gold membership expires?

Tags: dying-light

I recently bought Dying Light on my Xbox One because I loved it on Switch, but sold it. If I buy Xbox Live Gold on my Xbox, can I continue playing online with friends or other Xbox users after the membership expiration?